# Set task bar icon in windowsform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i need to assign icon in winform. but it does not appear in title bar, it's only visible in taskbar. 
even when i used these properties,

```
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
  FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
```

but when i apply these properties it is working but minimizebox and maximize buttons are not visible.

i need only icon visible in task bar not in title bar... it can't affect to other controls....

it is possible.. if it is possible please give procedures...

Thanks

Comment: Have you included different size icons in your project?

Comment: no i include only one icon in my project

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Form's property `ShowICon=False`

or you can set `FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;` and add three buttons for minimize, maximize and close accordingly(in Top -Right).

Comment: hi arshad... if i mentioned showicon=false it will not appear in taskbar also.. and if i assign borderstyle it will not appear minimize, maximize and close buttons

Comment: You can try second option.